# Paypal Web Payments Buttons

Tags: paypal

My website allows people to "sign up" for day trips. They must then pay a price based on their selection. Does paypal allow you to send your own payment values (as calculated by the amount of daytrips and the price of each one)?

Is there a way to program this value?

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ the Direct Payment API. I think it supports all your needs

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_dcc_hub-outside

Also, you can test your application in the PayPal Sandbox

https://developer.paypal.com/

> **How it works**
>
> For each payment, Direct Payment API
>   takes the billing address, transaction
>   amount, credit card information, and
>   item information as inputs. Within
>   seconds, the API returns a
>   confirmation that the transaction has
>   been processed.

Comment: Cheers mate, I just got off the phone with Paypal Customer service and they said it can't be done, but I got the distinct feeling that he didn't understand what I was trying to describe. Cheers